# PHP: adjust value in array key for a field matched by an input string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit nervous, this is my first question here, but I've worked pretty hard on this and could use some help.

I've made a processing sketch that accesses ,sorts, and saves csv lists by sending queries to the php script. It gets the sorted lists back and displays them.
(I don't want to get into xml or sql until later)

Now I am trying to make it possible to vote on the entries in the list.

In my code snippet below, I have a query come in from processing that votes on an entry by sending the string.

I would like to check the entry string passed from processing against the fields in the array, and adjust the score by adding one vote to it.

The code below does not break my other running code, but also does not adjust the votes.
I suspect there is some way I am not accessing the string value correctly, and wonder if anyone could advise me....

```
$ListV[]='score';
$ListV[]='entry';

<Snip>

if ($type == "voteUp") { 
  $Entry = $_GET['Entry'];
  if(($handle = fopen("List.csv", 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,',')) !== FALSE) {
          $ListV[$row]=$data;
          $row++;                       
        }
        fclose ($handle);

   $count = count($ListV);
   for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){  //foreach???
      if ($rListV[$i][1]==$Entry || strcmp($rListV[$i][1],$Entry)==0) {
             $score =int($rListV[$i][0]);
             $rListV[$i][0]=$score+1;
      }
   }           
  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');

  $listVote = fopen("List.csv",'w');
  foreach ($ListV as $values) {fputcsv($listVote,$values);}
  fclose($listVote);
  }
}
```

I believe I have constructed a viable 2d Array with score and entry fields.
The reason I put score first is so I can take advantage of key sorting and also use the array indexing (such as it is in php) when needed.

Please note, I am not trying to change the index with the voting in this list, just the score.
So results should be as below;

*Before voting:*

2157 Kittenz

2157 Dogz

11   Antelopez

*After voting for Dogz;*

2157 Kittenz

2158 Dogz

11   Antelopez

So, Kittenz is always index 1, Dogz is always index 2, and so on....
(the key sorting gives a sorted array later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it, and am answering belatedly.

Since there is no stable sorting in php (without additional code), I have kept the sorting and display of tables separate from the main csv list.

Here is the code that gets an entry from processing and votes on it;

```
else if ($type == "voteUp") {         //vote up query
  $eVote = $_GET['eVote'];           //get voted string
  $vList = loadCSV('List.csv');      //load main csv List  
  $count = count($vList);            //string search and add to score
  for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    if ($vList[$i]['entry']==$eVote || strcmp($vList[$i]['entry'],$eVote )==0) {
      $vList[$i]['score'] += 1;
    }
  saveCSV('List.csv',$vList);        //save new score to main csv List
  }
}
```

and the load and save csv functions...

```
function loadCSV($file)
{
   $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
   $header = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
   $data = array();
   while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {
    $row_assoc = array();
    foreach ($row as $key => $field) {
        $row_assoc[$header[$key]] = $field;
    }
    $data[] = $row_assoc;
   }
   fclose($handle);
   return $data;
}
function saveCSV($file,$array)
{
   $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
   $header = array("score","entry");
   fputcsv ($handle, $header, ",");
   foreach($array as $row){
     fputcsv($handle, $row, ",");
   }
   fclose($handle);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

the (overly complicated) part adjusting the vote count works with a nonexistent `$rListV`, then you put the original `$ListV` back in the file.

Comment: Thanks! an obvious typo, once you see it. The code still is not working, so I will check the string info coming in - otherwise does the code look ok? (if its complicated, I understand it better!)